# Does it make sense to think about a distribution of distributions?

Tags: distributions

If yes, can you give me some insights/links about it please.

Comment: That's really the topic of nonparametric bayesian inference ...

Comment: Check keywords like Dirichlet and Gaussian processes. They are distributions on distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for distributions index by a set of parameters, you could consider a distribution of those parameters as a distribution of distributions. E.g. the family of normals with $\mu \sim N(\mu_0,\sigma_\mu^2)$ and $\sigma \sim N(\sigma_0, \sigma_\sigma^2)$. If you are fitting a distribution to data, this sort of "distribution of distributions" is the fitted object.